# replace number with alphabet

Tags: python, replace, numbers, alphabetical

What is proper method to replace digits to alphabet in loop python
 `for i in range(0, randPile):
        randRock = random.randint(1, 8)
        print('Pile {}: {}'.format(i + 1, 'O' * randRock))
        rockList.append(randRock)`

I have output :

Pile 1: OOOOOO
Pile 2: OOOOO
Pile 3: OOOOOOOO

I want

A : 00000
B : 0000
C : 00000

Like this remove Pile 1 with A, Pile 2 with B and Pile 3 with C

Answer (score 0):

The `chr` built-in will return the unicode character at the supplied codepoint. `chr(65)` is `'A'`, `chr(66)` is `'B'` and so on. So `chr(i + 65)` should give you the correct letter of the alphabet.